# Popup menu for gtk+ application on GtkViewTree

Tags: python, gtk

I'm trying to make an application which is working with files.
That's why I have a GtkTreeView there which is responsible for displaying files and I need to create a popup menu on this widget in order to allow user to ignore some directories.

I was looking for this on the internet and I've found this manual with [example](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/menus.html#example)

Everything is fine, I managed to do that, but the problem is I managed to do that just for label, for some widgets it doesn't work (for instance for GtkViewTree)

When I create a GtkEventBox and enter a GtkViewTree instance in there my click is beeing ignored.

Can somebody explain me what is the reason for this? How this GtkViewTree widget differs from label?

thank you in advance

Comment: You pack a widget into an EventBox when that widget doesn't have its own gdk.Window to recieve events on. The GtkTreeView **does** have its own window so packing it in an Eventbox is unnecessary. Try connecting the 'button-press-event' signal to the GtkTreeView itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Popup menus on treeviews work fine, just connect the signal directly to the TreeView widget. You won't need the EventBox (this is just for widgets without a window).

```
widget.connect("button_press_event", on_button_press)

def on_button_press(widget, event):
    popup = get_popup_menu() # acquire your popup menu somehow
    popup.popup(None, None, None, event.button, event.time)
```